# One or more parameter values were invalid: dynamodb

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

```js
const dynamoDBConfig = require("../../config/dynamodb");
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
AWS.config.update(dynamoDBConfig.aws_remote_config);
var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();

var params = {
    TableName : "year",
    KeySchema: [       
        { AttributeName: "year", KeyType: "HASH"},  //Partition key
        { AttributeName: "title", KeyType: "RANGE" }  //Sort key
    ],
    // other properties, it is the same every time
};
dynamodb.createTable(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to create table. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("Created table. Table description JSON:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    }
});
```

You can notice my primary key is **year**, `AttributeName: "year", KeyType: "HASH"`.  If i just change table name too anything it workes fine. But, when i change,`AttributeName: "year", KeyType: "HASH"` to `AttributeName: "anything", KeyType: "HASH"` then it is generating error.

```js
Unable to create table. Error JSON: {
  "message": "One or more parameter values were invalid: Some index key attributes are not defined in AttributeDefinitions. Keys: [test, title], AttributeDefinitions: [title, year]",
  "code": "ValidationException",
  "time": "2021-01-28T05:33:33.723Z",
  "requestId": "H4S1BQ5LB4G46S594UTBK4QMVRVVASDASSFGFGF4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG",
  "statusCode": 400,
  "retryable": false,
  "retryDelay": 4.143072370771728
}
```

What is wrong, when I change the name of the primary key attribute?

### Full params

```js
var params = {
    TableName : "iam",
    KeySchema: [       
        { AttributeName: "test", KeyType: "HASH"},  //Partition key
        { AttributeName: "title", KeyType: "RANGE" }  //Sort key
    ],
    AttributeDefinitions: [       
        { AttributeName: "year", AttributeType: "N" },
        { AttributeName: "title", AttributeType: "S" }
    ],
    ProvisionedThroughput: {       
        ReadCapacityUnits: 10, 
        WriteCapacityUnits: 10
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is cause by the fact that your `KeySchema` **does not match** `AttributeDefinitions`.

In the `KeySchema` you have `test`, while in your `AttributeDefinitions` you have `year`. This obviously leads to your issue, as you can't have `AttributeDefinitions` which are not part of your `KeySchema`, nor part of schema of Local or Global Secondary Indices.

Comment: This worked, thank you. Can you provide me a good resource to learn dynamodb using nodejs. As I am a beginner in this field.

Comment: When i do 
    `AttributeDefinitions: [       
        { AttributeName: "id", AttributeType: "N" },
        { AttributeName: "title", AttributeType: "S" },
        { AttributeName: "hi",AttributeType:"S" }
    ]` then it generates the error, `umber of attributes in KeySchema does not 
exactly match number of attributes defined in AttributeDefinitions`

Comment: @Rahul  `AttributeDefinitions` must match `KeySchema`. I see you have tree `AttributeDefinitions`, but schema can have only 2.

Comment: `KeySchema: [       
        { AttributeName: "id", KeyType: "HASH"},  //Partition key
        { AttributeName: "title", KeyType: "RANGE" }  //Sort key
    ],`

Comment: @Rahul What is `AttributeName: "hi",AttributeType:"S"`?

Comment: `AttributeDefinitions: [       
        { AttributeName: "id", AttributeType: "N" },
        { AttributeName: "title", AttributeType: "S" },
        { AttributeName: "hi",AttributeType:"S" }
    ]`

Comment: @Rahul You can't have `hi` in `AttributeDefinitions`.

Comment: ` What is AttributeName: "hi",AttributeType:"S"` it is just for testing.

Comment: `You can't have hi in AttributeDefinitions`: how can i add another attribute

Comment: @Rahul You can't use it, that's why you have error. You can have only two attributes in `AttributeDefinitions` whitch match your schema. Nothing else. You can't add anything else unless you define LSI or GSI. DynamoDb is schema-less.

Comment: `DynamoDb is schema-less`: Ohh, this means, when i will upload my data, then i can have any number of attributes in Item. RIght?

Comment: @Rahul Yes, exactly. Thus you only define attributes for your primary key and sort key.

Comment: One more question, here i saw more that one attribute in attribute definition https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeTable.html

Comment: @Rahul Becuse that table uses Local and Global Secondary Indices. You are not using that, so you can't have more attributes.